# mysql subquery with inner join and limit

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

I have two tables `recipes_sa` with columns:

```
recipes_id   recipes_name   recipes_chef
----------   ------------   ------------
```

and `chefs_sa` with columns:

```
chefs_id   chefs_name
--------   ----------
```

And I want to get a limited number of recipes with their chef details, using `INNER JOIN` and `LIMIT`

I made the following function:

```
function getLimitJoinData($data, $tbls, $ids, $abr, $type, $limit) {

            $dataToSelect = implode($data, ',');

            $q = "SELECT $dataToSelect";

            $q.= " FROM (SELECT * FROM $tbls[0] LIMIT $limit) $abr";


            for ($i=1; $i < count($tbls); $i++) { 
                $q .= " ".$type." JOIN ". $tbls[$i] ." ON " . $abr.'.recipes_chef' .' = '. $ids[$i-1][0];   
            }
        }
```

And the query is like this

```
SELECT chefs_sa.chefs_name,
       recipes_sa.recipes_name 
FROM (SELECT * FROM recipes_sa LIMIT 8) rec 
INNER JOIN chefs_sa ON rec.recipes_chef = chefs_sa.chefs_id
```

But when I run the query I had the following warning:

> Warning: PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'recipes_sa.recipes_name'
>   I don't understand why

I have the column `recipes_name` in `recipes_sa` table, and from what I read that the database runs the “**inner query**” (the one with limit) first, then how the recipes_name column is not found !!

Comment: Notice.. That SQL is a unorderd dataset.. Without using `ORDER BY` when using `LIMIT` anny SQL server is free to return the records in anny order the server wishes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have aliased `recipes_sa` [AS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) `rec`. Use the following:

```
SELECT chefs_sa.chefs_name,
       rec.recipes_name 
FROM (SELECT * FROM recipes_sa LIMIT 8) rec 
INNER JOIN chefs_sa ON rec.recipes_chef = chefs_sa.chefs_id
```

Comment: I thought that the rec is to use after making the alias only 
Now it's work, thank's a lot

Comment: @IBMdig happy to help - go through this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html for a detailed understanding of how aliases work.

Comment: atleast link to official MySQL docs ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html ) not w3cschools... Besides that link you have provided is techical meant for the ANSI SQL standards it means..

Comment: @RaymondNijland edited. But personally, I prefer these simpler tutorials than official documentation for newbie developers, as they are easier to understand. Frankly, MySQL documentation requires multiple readings to get a hang of a particular feature.

Answer (score 3):

A different way of doing it is to order by recipes and then limit to the latest 8, rather than having a subquery :

```
SELECT cs.chefs_name, rs.recipes_name 
FROM recipes_sa rs
INNER JOIN chefs_sa cs ON rs.recipes_chef = cs.chefs_id 
ORDER BY rs.recipes_name ASC LIMIT 8
```

Comment: Can the person down voting leave a comment please?

Comment: There are atleast two errors in the query from syntax point of view.

Comment: @There is still a syntax error in ORDER BY clause part of your query. Regarding logical, there are multiple ways to do same thing in MySQL. Also, based on OP's comments, he was unclear about AS clause, so just needed to clarify that bit.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya So when someone gives a different way of doing things he gets down-voted now?

Comment: Downvoting because query had syntax errors and it still has those. I also get downvoted despite having correct concept, because the solution is syntactically wrong.

Comment: changed my vote post the edits. You should still use `rs.recipes_name` instead of `recipes_name` in `ORDER BY`